# How to determine BIOS age in Ubuntu

Tags: bios

My computer is old and it sometimes will not power on.  Is there a way to find its age, perhaps by looking at the BIOS installation date, in Ubuntu?  I am running Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Hey, I think I found it on my own (hurray!)  dmidecode

Comment: Why not write up an answer to your own question? Might help the next person with the same issue.

Comment: Wow, thanks, everyone!  I did think of writing up an answer myself but I feel like I get much better answers from the gurus who reply to my questions.  I built the computer myself from components so it has no brand name or model. I will post an answer per your suggestion, though.

Comment: Please note Ubuntu 14.04 has reached the end of its life (EOL). It is not updated any more. Questions about older versions of Ubuntu are off-topic here. Consider upgrading to a supported LTS version.

Comment: Yes, 14.04 is past its end of life.  I was unable to upgrade to 16.04 a few years ago because my video card is not supported by newer kernels.  Hence, the old age. :(

Comment: Will entering the BIOS allow you to see the information you need?

Comment: If you never changed disk, you can guesstimate total uptime form SMART: https://superuser.com/questions/686570/how-to-get-total-running-time-of-a-hard-disk

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is how I found the BIOS date on my computer in Ubuntu 14.04. It requires root privileges to use this command.

```
sudo dmidecode -s bios-release-date

04/18/2011
```

If you want more information than just the BIOS date, this command will give you lots of information:

```
sudo dmidecode | more

# dmidecode 2.12
SMBIOS 2.5 present.
68 structures occupying 2501 bytes.
Table at 0x0009F000.

Handle 0x0000, DMI type 0, 24 bytes
BIOS Information
    Vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
    Version: 0402   
    Release Date: 04/18/2011
    Address: 0xF0000
    Runtime Size: 64 kB
    ROM Size: 2048 kB
```

Comment: This also will work on newer versions of Ubuntu up to the latest 20.04

Comment: Beware of some (all?) mainboard manufacturers leaving lots of DMI fields in the state of "To Be Filled By O.E.M." (literally—for text fields, and possibly similar junk for some non-textual ones). See e.g. the relevant parts of output on my ZenBook UX333F: https://pastebin.com/raw/CNp47GNE .